# Laravel Optional Route Issue

Tags: php, laravel, routes, optional-parameters

My optional route looked like this:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'blog'], function ({

    Route::get('/', [
        'uses' => 'BlogController@showBlog',
        'as' => 'show.blog'
    ]);

    Route::get('{author}/{y?}/{m?}/{d?}/{title?}', [
        'uses' => 'BlogController@showDetailBlog',
        'as' => 'detail.blog'
    ]);

});
```

and its controller looked like this:

```
public function showDetailBlog($author, $year = null, $month = null, $date = null, $title = null)
{
    $user = User::where('username', $author)->first();

    if(!$year && !$month && !$date && !$title) {
        return view('pages.blog.author', compact('user'));

    } else {
        $blog = Blog::where('user_id', $user->id)->whereYear('created_at', $year)
            ->whereMonth('created_at', $month)->whereDay('created_at', $date)
            ->where('title_uri', $title)->first();
        $relates = Blog::where('category_id', $blog->category_id)->orderByDesc('id')->get();

        $tgl = Carbon::parse($blog->created_at);
        $uri = route('detail.blog', ['author' => $user->username, 'y' => $tgl->format('Y'),
            'm' => $tgl->format('m'), 'd' => $tgl->format('d'),
            'title' => $blog->title_uri]);

        return view('pages.blog.detail', compact('user', 'blog', 'relates', 'uri'));
    }
}
```

When I request it w/ full param like:

```
/blog/author123/2019/10/10/lorem-ipsum-dolor-sit-amet
```

It'll return correctly to a detail blog view. But when I request it only w/ author param like:

```
/blog/author123
```

It won't return to the author's blog view, and it always returns an empty array.

Does anyone know what I missed?

Comment: Silly question: why do you have `/blog/` in the URL, but not in the route? Are you in a route group? The route and the function are correct. But, from what you provided (unless you have a route group), both URL's should fail and hit your 404.

Comment: ya in a route group, w/ 'blog' as its prefix

Comment: @Raul well.. if u dont mind, check my route again ive just update it :v

Comment: Can you start debugging to make sure it's entering that part of the code? It is possible that you have another route that is overwriting this route and executing in another controller. I've saw that many times before. Ex: you might have a route /blog/authhor/{something}, and Laravel will match it first.

Comment: Your group callback is incorrect, try `Route::group(['prefix' => 'blog'], function () {`

Comment: @KFoobar i have a feeling that's a paste error. He said his code works, just not the right way. Without the `)`, he would have got syntax error :)

Comment: hehe ya just like what @Raul said, it's a typo

Comment: @Raul u're so damn right dude!!! There's a root that overwriting it, how silly i am lol. Tysm :)

Comment: You're welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

Oh my lord!! There's a route that overwriting it, that's why it returning an empty array. So, I just need to replace this get.title.blog route:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'blog'], function () {

    // other blog route

    Route::get('{title}', [
       'uses' => 'BlogController@getTitleBlog',
       'as' => 'get.title.blog'
    ]);

    Route::get('{author}/{y?}/{m?}/{d?}/{title?}', [
       'uses' => 'BlogController@showDetailBlog',
       'as' => 'detail.blog'
    ]);

});
```

into this:

```
Route::get('title/{title}', [
   'uses' => 'BlogController@getTitleBlog',
   'as' => 'get.title.blog'
]);
```

How silly I am, lol. But I cant realize this shit w/o ur help guys, especially @Raul tysm dude :D

Comment: yea also you can remove the else in your controller (since in the if statement you have a return already)

Answer (score 0):

```
public function showDetailBlog($author, $year = null, $month = null, $date = null, $title = null)
    {
        $user = User::where('username', $author)->first();

        if (!$user) abort(404);

        if (is_null($year) && is_null($month) && is_null($date) && is_null($title)) {
            return view('pages.blog.author', compact('user'));
        }

        $blog = Blog::where('user_id', $user->id);

        if (!is_null($year)) {
            $blog = $blog->whereYear('created_at', $year);
        }
        if (!is_null($month)) {
            $blog = $blog->whereMonth('created_at', $month);
        }
        if (!is_null($date)) {
            $blog = $blog->whereDay('created_at', $date);
        }
        if (!is_null($title)) {
            $blog = $blog->where('title_uri', $title);
        }
        $blog = $blog->first();


        $relates = Blog::where('category_id', $blog->category_id)
            ->where('id', '!=', $blog->id)
            ->orderByDesc('id')->get();

        $tgl = Carbon::parse($blog->created_at);
        $uri = route('detail.blog', ['author' => $user->username, 'y' => $tgl->format('Y'),
            'm' => $tgl->format('m'), 'd' => $tgl->format('d'),
            'title' => $blog->title_uri]);

        return view('pages.blog.detail', compact('user', 'blog', 'relates', 'uri'));
    }
```

Comment: hmm thx, but ive just tried and it still returning me an empty array..

Answer (score 0):

just try to this

```php
public function showDetailBlog($author, $year = null, $month = null, $date = null, $title = null)
{
    dd($author);
}
```

Check that you get `author123`

then try to add this :

```php
Route::get('{author}', [
        'uses' => 'BlogController@showDetailBlog',
        'as' => 'detail.blog'
    ]);
```

In your route to see if your controller is still hit by that route

On the other hand, you can use Laravel model binding !

In your RouteServiceProvider

```
public function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    Route::bind('author', function ($value) {
        return App\User::where('username', $value)->first() ?? abort(404);
    });
}
```

```php
public function showDetailBlog(User $author, $year = null, $month = null, $date = null, $title = null)
{
    dd($author); // You will have your author instance !
}
```